# sub command in Perl not executing when executed by cron

Tags: perl, cron, system

I have two Perl scripts: one pulls data from one system and writes to a CSV file and the other will execute against that data by pushing out a series of files once the first script gathers the list of IP addresses to push the files to.

When I run this manually at the command line, I can see the results of the first command generated, get the email, and then I can see the last command run with the results and the email from that. But today when the first script was run by cron, I only got the email with the list of IP addresses and not the results from the files pushed to the hosts. The time it takes for the command to run varies but it usually takes 1-2 minutes.

This is the last few lines that run in the first Perl script. An email is sent with attachments if there are hosts that meet the pull criteria and once that executes, the last line executes the push with reference to the output CSV file that contains the host IPs.

```
    system( "echo '' | mailx -s \"$payloademailsub\" -a $payloadoutputFile -a $wlsinfoFile $emails < /dev/null" );
}
else {
    system( "echo '' | mailx -s \"$payloademailsubnodup\" $emails < /dev/null" );
}

system("/bin/bash /usr/application/co/bin/webLogicPayload.bash < /usr/application/co/reports/pushPayload/weblogicHosts.csv");
```

This is the cron entry. The source command is required to pull in local custom variables and the app_setup is an application related file.

```
0 15 * * 1-5 . $HOME/app_setup; source ~/.bashrc; $HOME/application/co/weblogicHostReport.pl
```

Assuming this is cron-related since it will run manually, is there anything I should set in the cron entry or change in the Perl script that would help execute this completely?

Comment: Which user is running the cron? The `~` directory might not be what you think it is. The same goes for `$HOME`. Better to specify it explicitly with the user you want.

Comment: The user that executes this is the only user on the system, well that I am aware of. I also made a change to the path where the Perl script is executed to confirm just now by setting $HOME, reflected above and the script ran.

Comment: System accounts are users too. `cat /etc/passwd | wc -l` gives 40 users for my single user system. Standard advice with cron is to be explicit, don't assume environment like path or user variables. The actual user run depends on how you line it up, using crontab, /etc/crontab or /etc/cron.d.

Comment: That was one of the things I changed yesterday, I set it from absolute to using env variables to see if it would still run and it did. But for some reason it won't run the last command within the Perl script at the bottom. Even got the email, just not the execution of the push.